# How to upgrade existing graphenedb instance?

Tags: heroku, neo4j, heroku-toolbelt, graphenedb

How can you upgrade an existing graphenedb instance to the latest version?

I tried:

```
heroku addons:add graphenedb --version v220
Adding graphenedb on myApp ... failed
!    That type of add-on can only exist once per app and it already exists for myApp.
```

Or is it not possible and should I migrate the data to a new instance with the latest version?

BTW, I also tried `heroku addons:upgrade`. That was NOT what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Alberto, one of the founders of GrapheneDB.

As you have noticed, `$ heroku addons:upgrade graphenedb:plan` will upgrade the plan, not the version of Neo4j.

Currently **it's not possible to upgrade the version of Neo4j** through the UI or the Heroku CLI. There are two options:

1. Export your data store using the export feature in the admin tab. Download a copy. Remove the add-on, add it again with the new version of Neo4j and perform a restore (admin tab again) with the downloaded store file.
2. Open a support ticket specifying the database and the version you'd like to have and we'll do it for you.

Thanks for using GrapheneDB!